# Seach substring in string with a regex, get value and then replace it

Tags: php, regex, search, replace

i have a string like this:

```
"bla blabla bla bla [bla:bla:bla] blabla blablabla [ble:ble:ble] bla bla bla"
```

What i need is to find if theres a "[*:*:*]" in my string and get the content. From that i think i know how to replace it.

For a better explanation, the string is a description of something, and between the "[]" theres some parameteres to build an url, so there can be any number of "[]" in my string and i need the content as this the info needed to build the url.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need only if there are `[*:*:*]` what if there are more than two i.e `[*:*:*:*:*]`

Comment: I got the \[(.*?)\] (actually i got the "/\[[^\]]*\]/") but the problem is that regex will capture things like [text] that i dont want. The match has to be with the format [*:*:*].
There are always 3 substrings in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `\G` to assert the position at the end of the previous match and capture what is between `:` in a capturing group:

```
(?:\[|\G(?!\A))([^:\][]+)(?::|\])
```

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\[` Match [
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!\A)` Assert position at the end of previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^:\][]+` match 1+ times any char except the listed in the character class
- `)` close group 1
- `(?::|\])` Match either : or ]

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/700R6u/1)

Or use [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to match the 3 substrings between `[*:*:*]` to get all the values:

```
$pattern = "/\[((?:[^:]+:){2}[^:]+)\]/";
$str = "bla blabla bla bla [bla:bla:bla] blabla blablabla [ble:ble:ble] bla bla bla";

preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);

$result = array_map(function($x) {
    return explode(':', $x);
}, $matches[1]);

print_r($result);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => bla
            [1] => bla
            [2] => bla
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ble
            [1] => ble
            [2] => ble
        )

)
```

Comment: I think [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) is used for search and replacing but I think the OP wants the parts between to build a url that is why I chose `preg_match_all`. If you pass a string to `preg_replace_callback`, then a string is also returned and then you still have to get the separate parts.